# Does SO reputation give you a +100 bump on Electronics and Robotics?

Tags: support

All other sites seem to give you a +100 rep bump once you sign up if you have an SO account with sufficient points. Is that the case on Electronics and Robotics as well?

**UPDATE:** Clearing all associations and re-establishing them fixed the issue. It seems as though a bug was introduced briefly in the stackexchange code.

Comment: How do you log in -- Are you using an OpenID, or are you entering a username and password?

Comment: make your update an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

it should. did it fail to?

This has happened before. [We have record of it here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100).

Someone else has already submitted another bug on meta. I posted a link to your report. Sorry for the problem.

Comment: Seems to have failed: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/1968/dpp (http://stackoverflow.com/users/748/dpp)

Comment: Please check to make sure that your two accounts are associated under the accounts tab. I do not seem them as associated.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is described in [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/)  and [this meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites).

You need 100 reputation on an account. Then, go to the "Accounts" tab of your user page (on the site you just signed up for), and associate your accounts.

Are you following the steps in the linked article/question?

Comment: It does it automatically for my account on any site I join.

Comment: It's been intermittent when I try to join (using a Google OpenID).

Comment: I use google openID in general.